# Can a Catholic be an Anarchist?

Tags: catholicism, politics

Anarchy is the belief that the state in all its forms should be abolished (by rebellion or other means) and replaced entirely by groups that freely associate with each other.

What doctrines or disciplines would prevent a faithful Catholic from believing in anarchy? Does the Church teach the necessity of the state? Jesus says to pay taxes to rulers and Paul says to respect them but there is no mention on their necessity.

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean by 'anarchist' by providing a definition, a link to relevant wiki articles / dictionary, etc.  My instinct the answer is No, when the human laws are promulgated properly, consistent with natural law, and good for society ([Thomistic view of law Q. 90](https://www3.nd.edu/~afreddos/courses/406/law.htm)).  See also [Aquinas's Political Philosophy](https://iep.utm.edu/aqui-pol/) which favors law and order as a proper setting for humans to flourish.  So a potential anarchist need to show why it's better.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a Catholic cannot be an anarchist.

[Romans 13](https://aquinas.cc/la/en/%7ERom.C13):1-5 says we are to obey our "princes" (political leaders) because their authority comes from God; we obey them out of obedience to God:

> 1. Let every soul be subject to higher powers. For there is no power but from God: and those that are ordained of God.
> 2. Therefore, he that resisteth the power resisteth the ordinance of God. And they that resist purchase to themselves damnation.
> 3. For princes are not a terror to the good work, but to the evil. Wilt thou then not be afraid of the power? Do that which is good: and thou shalt have praise from the same.
> 4. For he is God's minister to thee, for good. But if thou do that which is evil, fear: for he beareth not the sword in vain. For he is God's minister: an avenger to execute wrath upon him that doth evil.
> 5. Wherefore be subject of necessity: not only for wrath, but also for conscience' sake.

cf. Pope Leo XIII's encyclical [*Diuturnum*](https://www.vatican.va/content/leo-xiii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_l-xiii_enc_29061881_diuturnum.html) on the origin of civil power.

Rebellion is not Christian. Satan, tempting Adam and Eve, was the first rebel; he said "*Non serviam*" ("I will not serve [God]."); cf. [*Revolution and Counter-Revolution*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=2845) by Plinio Corrêa de Oliveira.

The State is not a voluntary society (like a chess club, university, trade union, or corporation) but a necessary society. Pope Pius XI, [*Divini illiud magistri*](https://www.vatican.va/content/pius-xi/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-xi_enc_31121929_divini-illius-magistri.html) §11:

> there are three necessary societies, distinct from one another and yet harmoniously combined by God, into which man is born: two, namely the family and civil society, belong to the natural order; the third, the Church, to the supernatural order.

cf. [*Integralism*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7822) ch. 1, § "Division of societies".

Comment: Thanks! +1 for a good answer. I am not an anarchist (more libertarian), but I have many Bible believing friends who are anarchists that I asked this question for.